# How to solve BSOD: VSL Initialization Failed?

Tags: windows-10, bsod

So I tried to install HyperV (which use to work) all was going well, and the computer restarts and then I get a BSOD with the VSL Initialization failed...How do I fix it? and says it is going to restart, but it never does...

Answer (score 0):

Please try to install the latest chipset drivers and see if the blue screen of death issue still occurs.

The problem could also be because your processor does not support hardware virtualization. Although, this is probably unlikely because you implied that you may have had virtualization previously installed.

Did you uninstall it previously and now you are trying to reinstall it and get the issue? Or did you never have HyperV installed on your current hardware? We would need a little more info to help you with your problem further.

Comment: I had Hyper V installed, then I reinstalled Windows 10 to remedy some other issues I was having...and now this...however I disabled AMD Virtualization (in the BIOS) and it seems to be working OK now.

Comment: Oh, then you have another issue on your hands if you reinstalled the whole OS, but it is clearly a software issue not a hardware one.